# Django multi level template inheritance example?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Django documentation mentioned about three level template inheritance (http://djangobook.com/templates-in-views/). What is not clear is not to implement it.  Can somebody give an actual example?

Comment: there is no three-level structure actual example in Django docs.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the Django book is explicitly out of date and should not be used. And secondly, the Django documentation itself has a perfectly good explanation of [template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/language/#id1), along with an example of the three-level structure.

Comment: The Django book website was updated to Django 1.8 by a new author/maintainer, and is being updated for 1.11 LTS now.